# Why my easytags plugin not generating tags automatically?

Tags: tags, ctags, plugin-easytags

I have `xolox/vim-easytags` and `xolox/vim-misc` installed. I have following configuration in vimrc:

```
let g:easytags_dynamic_files = 1
let g:easytags_on_cursorhold = 1
let g:easytags_updatetime_min = 4000
let g:easytags_auto_update = 1
let g:easytags_async = 1
let g:easytags_by_filetype = '~/tagfiles'
let g:easytags_languages = {
\   'javascript': {
\     'cmd': 'jsctags',
\       'args': ['-f']
\   }
\}
```

and the `g:easytags_events`'s value is `['BufWritePost', 'CursorHold', 'CursorHoldI']`

Now I hold my cursor for more than 10 seconds, but the tags is not updated to `~/.vimtags` or any other possible tag files, what's the problem here?

But tags will be updated when I write the buffer to file.

Comment: Does it update with `:doautocmd CursorHold`? What's the output of `:set eventignore?`?

Comment: If all fails, try [gutentags](https://github.com/ludovicchabant/vim-gutentags), seems well maintained.

Comment: Why don't you use the plugin's issue tracker/mailing list?

Comment: @IngoKarkat, no, it still doesn't update with `:doautocmd CursorHold`. the output of `:set eventignore?` is empty.

Comment: Hm, then the autocmd isn't triggered. According to your config, it should be defined. You can check via `:autocmd CursorHold`; a call to easytags should be listed there.